# Do not want to show null values in excel

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to filter some records by using Filter formula in Pivot Table, I'm getting the values which I want to be shown but I'm also getting *VALUE!* symbol in some cells also, I do not want to display **0** or anything else in the place of *VALUE!*. How can I don it? Below is the formula I've used in Pivot table.

`=Filter(B1:B15,B1:B15>0)`

I know the actual formula of filter but I want to show values which are greater than zero only so, now I'm confused that how I can do it with formula only.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the table and select Pivot Table Options:

[image]

Comment: actually, I want to eliminate the values who are equals to zero and want to display the values greater than 0. can I achieve it by using any other formula?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula.

```
=FILTER(B1:B15,IF(ISERROR(B1:B15)=FALSE,B1:B15>0))
```

Comment: actually I want to display values which are greater than and want to eliminate all the values which are equals to zero. Can I use any other formula?